# Reduce blob size in javascript

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, gstreamer

Working on video recording application (using WebRTC), I record video/audio using getUserMedia() and stored data in blob, complete blob size is around 5MB (Audio+Video) for 10 Sec with 320X240px. code is here (set all audio/video constraint, low resolution, bit-rate, and frame-rate)

```
 var video = document.createElement('video');
 video.controls = true;
 video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blobs.video);
 console.log("Blob Size "+blobs.video)
```

How can I reduce blob size without reducing quality of audio/video. Using ([BinaryJs](http://binaryjs.com)) I am trying to convert this data from 32-bit float to 8 bit data, but still blob size remain same.

Comment: Post the constraints please.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is encoding the video and audio using asm.js.

Comment: @aergistal My audio video constraints  ` {
 "audio": true,
 "video": {
  "mandatory": {
   "minWidth": "320",
   "minHeight": "640",
   "minFrameRate": "10",
   "minAspectRatio": "4.3",
   "maxWidth": "640",
   "maxHeight": "480",
   "maxFrameRate": "15",
   "maxAspectRatio": "4.3"
  },
  "optional": []
 }
}`

Comment: You can use `MediaStreamRecorder.js` to compress/encode the video in `webm` with `vp8`. The problem is it works differently on Firefox (1 webm file) and Chrome (1 webm file + 1 wav file).

Comment: @aergistal I previously tried with [MediaStreamRecorder.js] (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/msr/MultiStreamRecorder.html), but my problem was not solved. Check following log, what I am getting in console of chrome, for 5 Sec recording. 

canvas resolutions 320 * 240
MediaStreamRecorder.js:561 video width/height 320 * 240

MediaStreamRecorder.js:481 using audio buffer-size: 2048
MediaStreamRecorder.js:393 audio recorded blob size: 877 KB
MediaStreamRecorder.js:589 video recorded blob size: 1.32 MB
MediaStreamRecorder.js:393 audio recorded blob size: 885 KB

Comment: @SantoshShingare what did you use at last  ?